# finding all possible combinations from a given number

Tags: php, numbers

How can I find all possible combinations from a given 3 digit number using PHP?
for example if the number is `123`, the possible array results should be following

```
123,132,213,321,321,312
```

and when a number repeats, there should be no duplicates.
example

```
$threedigit="001";
```

result should be

```
001,010,100
```

there is more possible numbers.

How I achieve this using PHP ?

Comment: Sorry, do not be offended by above comment. But just asking for a solution here won't help you learn. You need to work through such things yourself. This place is to ask for help if you ran into an issue you really cannot solve yourself. But for that you have to start yourself. And present your solution so far inside the question along with a precise explanation. This place is _not_ a free coding service, we are not here to do your work for you.

Comment: Posting your "not proper code" certainly would be the first step. Sorry, but that is how this site works. _That is documented ..._

Comment: As a general direction: you split the input string into three separate characters. Then you use three nested loops to iterate over all characters in each loop. And store all concatenations of those characters in an output array. Last you filter out doubles from that result.

Comment: I posted an answer to bring this question to something at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an example of a simple solution for a fixed length of 3 digits:

```
<?php
function permutations($input) {
  $digit = str_split($input, 1);
  $output = [];
  for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<3; $j++) {
      if ($i==$j) continue;
      for ($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
        if ($i==$k || $j==$k) continue;
        $output[] = $digit[$i] . $digit[$j] . $digit[$k];
      }
    }
  }
  return array_unique($output);
}
print_r(permutations("123"));
print_r(permutations("001"));
```

The obvious output contains first 6, second 3 entries:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 132
    [2] => 213
    [3] => 231
    [4] => 312
    [5] => 321
)
Array
(
    [0] => 001
    [1] => 010
    [4] => 100
)
```

Comment: thank you so much for spending time for my silly question, but the result was supposed to be different. as I mentioned in the question, if the given number is 123 each number should be taken only once to generate each 3 digit numbers. so 123 should generate only 6 x 3 digit numbers.

Comment: OK, my mistake. I added a simple condition so that only the six combinations are created. I currently fail to see the logic behind the last statement you wrote about a repeated digit.

Comment: Right, got the idea now. Sorry, toll a minute. I again updated the answer, that algorithm should deliver what you asked. It uses positional parameters and insists, that no position is taken twice.